# Random bytes and encodings

Tags: random, encoding

I have a function that needs a random sequence of bytes as input (e.g. a salt for hashing a password). I generate that string using a CSPRNG function and then encode in to base64.
Now I pass that string to the function that needs it, but that function works with bytes, so if it receive a string it turns it into a byte-buffer by reading the string as utf8. The string given as input is not the same sequence of bytes generated with the CSPRNG function but is the utf8 decoded string of the base64 encoded random bytes. So if I generate N bytes, the transformations with encodings turns it in 4/3*N bytes. Can I assume that these expanded bytes are still random after the transformations? Are there any security implications?

Here's a pseudo code to make it more clear:

```
function needsRandBytes(rand) {
  if (typeof rand == 'string') {
    rand = Buffer.from(rand, 'utf8'); // here's the expansion
  }

  // use the rand bytes...
}

randBytes = generateRandomBytes(N); // cryptographically secure function
randString = randBytes.toString('base64');

needsRandBytes(randString);
```

Comment: No, you can't assume that string-re-encoded bytes are still random.  It very much depends on the encoding - UTF16 vs ascii would behave very differently.  Why can't you just use the bytes?

Comment: I can, but this is just an example, I've seen this kind of behaviour in a few code bases and I would like to know if it is secure to do so. Seems a strange thing to me, but I'm not a security expert, I don't want to say something wrong

Comment: Sounds like you ought to trust your gut on this.  Ask the developer who wrote it (if you are close to them) to explain how this maintains provable randomness in all platforms in which this will run now and in the future.

Comment: You are not destroying entropy, but you are decreasing entropy per byte. If a CSPRNG can be made predictable by a simple coding transformation, it wouldn't be a CSPRNG. As far as security implications go, asking this question on [security.se] would make more sense.

Comment: A side effect of the encoding is that the resulting bytes might no longer be uniformly distributed but instead be biased towards certain bytes. Whether or not the resulting bias is exploitable in a realistic scenario is another question. My guess is that it wouldn't be, but why run the risk?